# Why showing squere for \u0085 in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, utf-8

I used language file to define my Buttons name.But last year this was working fine.

```
x.client.k.OpenButton=Open\u0085
```

But suddenly now `\u0085` shown as squire.I need some expert explanation what happening ?
I used utf-8 formatting and java 8.I used language key, to translate app, English and Swedish.

[image: aa]

Comment: Your font can't show that character

Comment: it is new line character? do, why it not identify. ?

Comment: Use `\n` for a newline. Also, that unicode doesn't look like a newline (`\u000a`)

Comment: What are you expecting the "next line" character to show up as?

Comment: In case it's not clear, \uXXXX is a notation for a UTF-16 code unit that can be used in certain types of programming language sources and data documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), the character with hex value 85 is an `…` ellipsis.

Unicode is however based on [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), where characters 80-9F are control characters, i.e. basically non-printable characters. Non-printable characters are often display as a `□` square ([`\u25A1`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm)), and invalid characters display as a `�` question mark ([`\uFFFD`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)).

Replace [`\u0085`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm) with [`\u2026`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm), which is the Unicode code point for `…` ellipsis, so that your button text will show as:

`Open…`

Comment: Or, just use 3 individual `'.'` ([`\u002e`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm)), aka period, characters instead of using 1 Unicode ellipsis character: `x.client.k.OpenButton=Open...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau but depending on the font, `…` may look different than `...`…